# What could stop the Apache redirects. And what cause these redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What could stop the Apache redirects. And what cause these redirects?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^https://somedomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/public/index\.php?url=$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Using somedomain.com/login
I am getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

https://somedomain.com/public/index.php?url=public/index.php&url=public/index.php<...>

I believe L should stop the redirects? Does not?

Comment: Do you use a routing framework like symfony?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe L should stop the redirects? Does not?

No `L` doesn't stop redirect. `L` flag (Last) just stops current `mod_rewrite` loop and causes `mod_rewrite` rules to loop again from start so it works like `continue` in a `while` loop.

You must remove `http://` and `R=301` flag from your last routing rule to avoid an external redirection.

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{ENV:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^t/(.*)$ public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thank you! But now i am getting very long redirect.

Comment: It works, but to reach page somedomain.com/login takes a minute

Comment: That cannot be due to rules. Rules just take few mili seconds to execute. You can test in Chrome dev tool see to see timing stats.

Comment: Finally, managed to shorted the redirect to a second, by inserting an additional paramter to url, i.e. some letter. instead of `somedomain.com/login`  i use `somedomain.com/t/login`.  And the last rule then is `RewriteRule ^t/(.+)$ public/index\.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: i mean using the answer and the question code it takes minutes to load the website. But if i insert one mo word/letter to url the redirection problem is resolved.  Do not understand fully how these rules interact, and why performance is improved more then 100 times. Made a separate question for this.